# Using self-built approaches in Lucene search engine

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search, search-engine, keyword-search

I'm looking for an appropriate search engine that I can use my own similarity measure and tokenization approaches in it. Lucene search engine is introduced as a good one for this purpose but I have no idea about that. I searched on the internet about the tutorial of new versions of Lucene search engine but most of the pages are from a few years ago. Some of my questions are as follow:

1. Is it possible to change the similarity measure, tokenization and Stemming approaches and use self-built classes in the Lucene? If yes, How to do that?
2. Is there any difference between how we index the text for keywords search or phrasal search? should I make two different index for keyword search and phrasal search? (I think if we remove stop words, it will affect on the result of phrasal search and if I don't remove stop words, it will affect on the result of keyword search, won't it?)

Any information about this topic is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, yes, and we do it on a couple solutions at my workplace. [Here is a reasonable tutorial on how to do this](https://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2014/01/20/build-your-own-custom-lucene-query-and-scorer/). The tutorial uses Solr, which is a good Lucene implementation. To answer your questions directly:

1. Yes, there is a way to do this by overriding interfaces and providing your own implementation (see tutorial). Tokenization can be done without needing to override classes within Solr's default configuration, depending on how funky you need to get with Tokenization.
2. Yes, making an index that will return accurate results is a measure in understanding how your users will be searching the index. That having been said, a large part of the complexity in how queries search comes from people wanting matching results to float to the top of the results list, which is done via scoring. Given it sounds like you're looking to override the scoring, it may not matter for you. You should note though that by default, Lucene will match on hits to multiple columns higher than a single match exactly on a single column. That means that if you store data across many columns (and you search by default across many columns) your search will get less and less "accurate".

Full text search against a single column tends to be pretty accurate phrase vs words, but you'll end up with a pretty large index.

Comment: Dear @patrick . Could you please explain the answer of my second question? In my application, I need to search by keywords and also search by collocations. Because someone said to me it's better to search by collocations and combine the results by the result of keyword search. So, I extracted keywords and collocations.  But I don't know I have to make distinct index for keyword search and phrasal search or just one index is enough?

Comment: Just one index would be enough - you could store them in separate columns within the index, and parse the user's search into "<full text> OR <collocation>" and if it matched on both, that would be weighted towards the top. Alternatively, you could mark the collocations and synonyms or similar words to get those words to float towards the top. Lucene and Solr both allow you to define synonyms lists that are interpreted at weighting-time.

Comment: good answer. one thing that's not so nice. you mix up with lucene and solr. that's not the same. lucene is a java based fulltext search library (so pretty low level). Solr is a "search engine" as webserver implementation based on lucene. depending on your architectural needs you may use one or the other

Comment: @patrick . I have another question: How many keywords can we use in each query? Is there any maximum number for that? or it's completely depend on the corpus and the query terms? What if I want to use collocations instead of keywords?

Comment: There IS a hard limit (I think 1024?) to the number of terms you can query. You can use collections to search similar with the following syntax: field_to_search:('term1' 'term2')